# Treshold values row-wise in a dataframe

Tags: r

Consider an example data frame:

```
A   B   C   v
5   4   2   3
7   1   3   5
1   2   1   1
```

I want to set all elements of a row to 1 if the element is bigger or equal than `v`, and 0 otherwise. The example data frame would result in the following:

```
A   B   C   v
1   1   0   3
1   0   0   5
1   1   1   1
```

How can I do this efficiently? The number of columns will be much higher, and I would like a solution that does not require me to specify the names of the columns individually, and will apply it to all of them (except `v`) instead.

My solution with a for loop is way too slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can create a logical matrix and coerce to binary

```
df1[-4] <- +(df1[-4] >= df1$v)
```

Comment: Very slick.Can generalize `df1[!names(df1)=='v'] <- +(df1[!names(df1)=='v'] >= df1$v)
`...since number of columns may vary, as well as location of `v`.